# Basic 4-function Java Calculator with Swing

Tags: java, swing, calculator

I can see that there are a lot of java calculators on here, so I hope it hasn't gotten too old. This is a basic 4-function calculator in java using the swing interface. I am positive that it is inefficient, so don't hold back or anything. Here's the code, leaving out the code auto-generated by Netbeans for the swing interface (though my the source file  is [here](https://github.com/Grimmslaw/Calculator/blob/master/src/CalcViewer/CalcView.java), if you need to look at it):

```
package CalcViewer;

/**
 *
 * @author wesrickey
 */
public class CalcView extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    String expression = "";
    String[] expressionArray;
    String firstTerm;
    String secondTerm;
    double firstDoub;
    double secondDoub;
    boolean isResult = false;

    /**
     * Creates new form CalcView
     */
    public CalcView() {
        initComponents();
    }

    public double doCalc(char op) {

        double result = 0;

        // couldn't get the regex to work as one term, so this'll have to do for now
        if (expression.contains("+")) {
            expressionArray = expression.split("\\+");
        } else if (expression.contains("-")) {
            expressionArray = expression.split("-");
        } else if (expression.contains("*")) {
            expressionArray = expression.split("\\*");
        } else if (expression.contains("/")) {
            expressionArray = expression.split("/");
        }

        firstDoub = Double.parseDouble(expressionArray[0]);
        secondDoub = Double.parseDouble(expressionArray[1]);

        if (op == 'p') {
            result = firstDoub + secondDoub;
        } else if (op == 'm') {
            result = firstDoub - secondDoub;
        } else if (op == 't') {
            result = firstDoub * secondDoub;
        } else if (op == 'd') {
            result = firstDoub / secondDoub;
        }

        isResult = true;
        return result;
    }

    // same story as above with the regex not working for me
    public boolean hasPattern(String input) {
        if (input.contains("+")) {
            return true;
        } else if (input.contains("-")) {
            return true;
        } else if (input.contains("*")) {
            return true;
        } else if (input.contains("/")) {
            return true;
        } else return false;
    }
```

(auto-generated layout code)

```
    private void btnOneActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnOneActionPerformed
        setFocusable(true);

        if (isResult) {
            isResult = false;
        }
        expression += "1";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnOneActionPerformed

    private void btnTwoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnTwoActionPerformed
        if (isResult) {
            isResult = false;
        }
        expression += "2";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnTwoActionPerformed

    private void btnThreeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnThreeActionPerformed
        if (isResult) {
            isResult = false;
        }
        expression += "3";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnThreeActionPerformed

    private void btnFourActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnFourActionPerformed
        if (isResult) {
            isResult = false;
        }
        expression += "4";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnFourActionPerformed

    private void btnFiveActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnFiveActionPerformed
        if (isResult) {
            isResult = false;
        }
        expression += "5";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnFiveActionPerformed

    private void btnSixActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnSixActionPerformed
        if (isResult) {
            isResult = false;
        }
        expression += "6";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnSixActionPerformed

    private void btnSevenActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnSevenActionPerformed
        expression += "7";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnSevenActionPerformed

    private void btnEightActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnEightActionPerformed
        expression += "8";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnEightActionPerformed

    private void btnNineActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnNineActionPerformed
        if (isResult) {
            isResult = false;
        }
        expression += "9";
        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnNineActionPerformed

    private void btnZeroActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnZeroActionPerformed
        if (isResult) {
            isResult = false;
        }

        if (!expression.equals("0")) {
            expression += "0";
        }

        textDisplay.setText(expression);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnZeroActionPerformed

    private void btnClearAllActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnClearAllActionPerformed
        expression = "";
        textDisplay.setText("0");
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnClearAllActionPerformed

    private void btnPlusActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnPlusActionPerformed
        if (!hasPattern(expression)) {
            expression += "+";
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnPlusActionPerformed

    private void btnSubtractActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnSubtractActionPerformed
        if (!hasPattern(expression)) {
            expression += "-";
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnSubtractActionPerformed

    private void btnMultiplyActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnMultiplyActionPerformed
        if (!hasPattern(expression)) {
            expression += "*";
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnMultiplyActionPerformed

    private void btnDivideActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnDivideActionPerformed
        if (!hasPattern(expression)) {
            expression += "/";
        }
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnDivideActionPerformed

    private void btnEqualsActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnEqualsActionPerformed
        double resultDoub;
        String resultString;

        // does the calculation base on the input operation
        if (expression.contains("+")) {
            resultDoub = doCalc('p');
        } else if (expression.contains("-")) {
            resultDoub = doCalc('m');
        } else if (expression.contains("*")) {
            resultDoub = doCalc('t');
        } else if (expression.contains("/")) {
            resultDoub = doCalc('d');
        } else {
            resultDoub = 0;
        }

        // sets result as a double if a double and an integer if an integer
        // as opposed to before when everything displayed as a double
        if (!(resultDoub % 1 == 0)) {
            resultString = Double.toString(resultDoub);
        } else {
            int resultInt = (int)resultDoub;
            resultString = Integer.toString(resultInt);
        }

        expression = resultString;

        textDisplay.setText(resultString);
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnEqualsActionPerformed

    private void btnDecimalActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {//GEN-FIRST:event_btnDecimalActionPerformed
        expression += ".";
    }//GEN-LAST:event_btnDecimalActionPerformed

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalcView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalcView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalcView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalcView.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CalcView().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    private javax.swing.JButton btnClearAll;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnClearEntry;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDecimal;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnDivide;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEight;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnEquals;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnFive;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnFour;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnMultiply;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnNine;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnOne;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPlus;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnPositiveNegative;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSeven;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSix;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnSubtract;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnThree;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnTwo;
    private javax.swing.JButton btnZero;
    private javax.swing.JTextField textDisplay;
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables
}
```

One of the main flaws that I'm aware of is my `hasPattern();` method. I had to use that to check if the expression has an operator in it, since I could not for the life of me get the regular expression for that pattern to work, so I improvised.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### General code style

#### positives

- you respect java naming conventions
- you don't use static methods
- at least one comment tells *why* the code is the way it is.

#### negatives

- you inherit from `JFrame` without changing its behavior.
- you have a lot of duplicated code.
- you use `double` (and not `BigDecimal`) which has accuracy issues.
- most comments repeat what the codes does an are therefore obsolete.
- some comments "structure" the method.
- you create a "structured string" for further processing which needs parsing afterwards.
- you declare the member variables at the bottom of the class, they should be on top.

### suggestions

#### structured string

As long as you plan to handle 2 numbers only create an array of  `StringBuilder` variables  with size of 2.
create a "counter" that is toggled between `0` and `1` when an operator button is clicket. Convert the numberst to BigIntegers before passing them to the calculation method.

store the operator in a variable of its own and pass it along with the numbers as separate parameter to the calculation method. This way you don't have to deal with regexp...

#### code duplication

The suggestions above will eliminate most of your `if/else` cascades.

In your main you catch each exception type individually but the action taken is the same for all. Replace all the `catch` blocks with a single one catching a more general exception type, preferably `Exception`